# Application Insights - No data for dependency duration

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I am not getting data for any dependency calls (Azure SQL calls) in one of my clients'  Application Insights which is running an Azure Web App. Initially, I thought the application is on older version of .Net (4.0), and then I created a sample Azure Web App with the latest ASP.NET  5 template with Azure SQL as database. Even for this one, no dependency call related data in Application Insights. Both the applications have been deployed successfully in Azure and I am checking the Application Insights data in the Azure portal. Any clue what is going on ..where should I check?
[image]

Comment: i believe to get "automatic" collection of dependencies, you have to be on .net 4.6 or higher?  I'm checking internally to find out if ASP.NET5 (asp.net core?) supports this out of the box or not.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet v.1.0.0-rc1-update3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet/1.0.0-rc1-update3) installed (not that 1.0.0-rc1 that is default with VS2015). v.1.0.0-rc1-update3 should also install Dependency Collector module, so you should have HTTP/SQL dependencies collected by default for full framework. Just verified this is the case.